# Android Background Task - Less Than 15 Minutes

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm trying to run a background task more often than the 15 minutes minimum set by Android.

Battery life isn't a concern and it's for internal use only. I have tried disabling battery optimisation for the app, but that doesn't work either.

Is there anyway to opt out of the battery optimisation?

```
const component = new android.content.ComponentName(context, org.nativescript.location.BackgroundService26.class);
const builder = new android.app.job.JobInfo.Builder(1, component);        builder.setRequiredNetworkType(android.app.job.JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
builder.setPeriodic(10000)
builder.setRequiresCharging(false);
const jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
const service = jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

Comment: create alarm manager -> broadcast -> service doing work -> create alarm manager again

Comment: As @RofieSagara mentioned, use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) instead.

Comment: @Manoj could I also use PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK?

Comment: If you don't really have to worry about battery usage, you could use that.

Comment: @Manoj battery usage isn't a concern - the device will always have a power source. I can get a WAKE_LOCK to work, but I can't get the code right for PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK. Do you know if a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK works in the latest version of NativeScript?

Comment: It has nothing to do with {N} version, it's going to be native code written in JS / TS. Refer the [Android marshalling docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/overview).